# creating file error - file is being used?

Tags: c#

What I want to do - Have two nested for loops. Outer generates string filename and creates filename if it does not exist, inner generates string to be written to filename. It appends strings to this filename. The process is repeated for every filename we want.

I tried using (partial code) -

```
string path = @"path here";
File.Create(path);
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, true);

outer for loop{
file.WriteLine(strMsg);
}

file.Close();
```

The file is created, but nothing is written to it and i get an error - file 'xyz' is being used by another process. How to fix this ?

Comment: Please post full code sample.

Comment: @Dan - not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) method creates *and opens* the file.  You are ignoring the `FileStream` return value, which means that it's not being closed.

When you then try to open the file with `StreamWriter`, it's already opened, which will fail.

In this case, just leave out `File.Create` entirely.  `StreamWriter`'s constructor will create the file for you:

```
using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, false))
{
    for // ... outer for loop
    {
        file.WriteLine(strMsg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to dispose the stream objects that get created to release the file lock. `File.Create` in particular is not disposed so it will still hold a lock on the file that was just created.

```
string path = @"path here";
File.Create(name).Dispose();  // Kill the lock immediately.
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
outer for loop{
file.WriteLine(strMsg);
}
// Stream will close automatically when leaving the using block.
```

Comment: Why even use File.Create?

Comment: Thanks for showing me alternate approaches. My code is bad, but its helpful to know your method too.

Comment: @ReedCopsey This was not a complete code sample. The create could have been happening elsewhere and then subsequently you may want to write to file (which I would use a File.WriteAllText anyway). If you always wanted the file to be created this is still correct, if you only wanted to create if you were writing the file then I guess it's pointless.

Answer (score 0):

File.Create returns a FileStream, which you are ignoring.

Perhaps something more like this?

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) {}
```

will allow you to keep your code otherwise intact and resolve the issue?

Comment: Why create the file in advance at all?

Comment: Ask the original poster.... I was just posting the answer to his question without requiring his re-writing it entirely. I would have done it the way you mentioned or File.WriteAllText(fn, "") to create it.